In CASL for ABAC, how do you pass dynamic conditions in the JSON?
I want to pass conditions into CreateMongoAbility through a JSON object, being specified in a database somewhere.
In the documentation it looks easy:
{
  "action": 'delete',
  "subject": 'Post',
  "conditions": { "published": "true" }
}

... but I need to pass a dynamic condition (in this case, the identity.id):
{
  "action": 'delete',
  "subject": 'Post',
  "conditions": { "authorId": "identity.id" }
}

I feel like I may not understand how the JSON is being converted into rules. Do I need to provide JSON rules with all literals? For example:
{
  action: 'delete',
  subject: 'Post',
  conditions: { authorId: '123456'}
}

... and hence I need to parse the JSON object and replace the identity.id with the actual identifier?
NOTE
I have found a way around this by converting the JSON to a string, searching and replacing the JSON with the value I want:
I first change the JSON in the database to this:
{
  "action": 'delete',
  "subject": 'Post',
  "conditions": { "authorId": "$identity.id" }
}

Then I replace the data I need for CASL rules:
  const jsonString = JSON.stringify(caslJSONfromDatabase);
  const jsonHydrated = jsonString.replace("$identity.id", identity.id);
  const jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonHydrated);

However, this seems like a hack and not the proper way to do this.
Thanks!

This is just a common way to solve this problem.
You either have permissions per user in the database with all different combinations (I.e., ids and relations) or you have a template with variables inside and replace those in runtime.
Instead of storing and retrieving JSON object you can store conditions as serialized JSON template. By the way, you can use any template engine you want to interpolate variables, I usually show it with JSON.parse because it’s the simplest option which doesn’t require external libs.
Also you can find an example in cookbook:
https://casl.js.org/v6/en/cookbook/roles-with-persisted-permissions
